# Installing libpng on a Mac with Maverick

Tags: mac, perl, osx-mavericks, cpan

I want to install `libpng` library on my Mac, which runs under Mavericks.
Here is a simple Perl script to check if it is ok:

```
use GD;
my $gd = GD::Image->new();
my $ok = $gd->can('png') ? 'Yes' : 'No';
print "$ok\n";
```

Of course, running this script (`perl my-test.pl`) returns `No`.

So I followed the documentation [here](http://www.underworldproject.org/documentation/LibpngDownload.html), and I run the following commands:

```
port install xorg-server
port install xorg-libXmu
port install libxml2
port install libpng
```

(all of them with `sudo`). 
But still, no luck with my test script.

I've tried a manual installation too, with the following command:

```
cd /usr/local/src
curl --location --output libpng-1.6.8.tar.gz http://download.sourceforge.net/libpng/libpng-1.6.8.tar.gz
tar -xzvf libpng-1.6.8.tar.gz
cd libpng-1.6.8
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libpng-1.6.8
make
make install
ln -s libpng-1.6.8 /usr/local/libpng
```

([source](http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/libpng/))

Unfortunately, the script continues to return `No`.

Using CPAN, if I try to run `install Image::PNG::Libpng`, it fails with an error:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/Libpng.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 20 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  13
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=9, Tests=54,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.08 usr  0.03 sys +  0.51 cusr  0.10 csys =  0.72 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/9 test programs. 1/54 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  BKB/Image-PNG-0.20.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports BKB/Image-PNG-0.20.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
  Already tried without success
Failed during this command:
 BKB/Image-PNG-0.20.tar.gz                    : make_test NO
```

Using `force install Image::PNG::Libpng` doesn't help neither.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or what can I do to complete my installation?

Sorry if I missed some details, or logs from commands. Do not hesitate to ask me more details...

Answer (score 0):

Did you do the final step of setting up the environment variables and then restarting the shell session before trying your tests?

What does `echo $PNG_DIR` at the command prompt give you? A blank line or a line containing `/usr/local`?

Comment: I've tried to set this `PNG_DIR` variable, but still it does not work.